# Импорт данных товара из 1с на сайт

Tags: modx, 1с

Всем привет!

Начинаю разбираться в коде mSklad (кто не в курсе, это один из платных компонентов Modx по обмену данных сайта с 1с). Руководство поставило задачу вместо стандартной передачи данных номенклатуры товаров и цен передать уже несколько типов цен и организаций, наименования товаров. Установил следующее дополнение к 1с: ссылка в файле 1c_exchange.php нашел получение параметров на 69 строке:

```
$response = $mSklad->catalog->import(@$_REQUEST['filename'], @file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

После чего идет вызов файла mskladCatalogHandler.class.php функции import. Хотел спросить, откуда берутся данные `$_REQUEST['filename']`? В моем случае вместо двух файлов import.xml и offers.xml будет целых шесть папок, в которых будут лежать файлы. Структура папок такова примерно:

```
1/
   import___4b9c5e01-4ce3-4465-8e81-8fc5f856ce78
   offers___3a673c12-70f8-4f96-b6f0-158d3c32ed11
   prices___38032344-959e-44c7-bfe7-f66f87f0b55a
   rests___18623ce1-1723-461f-8294-66b03197d744
2/
   import___3f7b3b2d-5b73-46c6-8308-ef09d1abcad0
   offers___7a212499-e028-49ee-803a-92c4491dc310
   prices___5c29a319-5d70-426d-9b1b-12ee1a9a9a3d
   rests___80fcf9d1-1d9f-42be-95e5-c56973b87a96
3/
   import___2c09ffa4-5ce3-4570-bdac-55c3598a1455
   offers___0e1491b9-0bcd-4e13-bcc2-37be49acae26
   prices___0902f2df-9d95-49bd-a596-5fe2ce887eb6
   rests___e9dfb23f-a7de-4657-9a59-cb1893aa7aac
4/
   import___d2fd4552-4446-4e5f-b491-3b8a01786087
   offers___f9ee4524-022c-4ab7-82e9-28bb4f52abee
   prices___ff32f84a-7a39-4b16-8986-c9b4670e73b9
   rests___3b8b2c81-5fa8-4181-9bdb-eb8d8623ae35
5/
  import___fcca2bad-ee98-4fd4-a9a2-c1f2a39f367b
  offers___06b6bb43-27d1-419e-9653-48418975c75c
  prices___ba2a4524-418a-4c95-8b4e-4e1abfaa96ad
  rests___72cf5fa4-e695-4039-ab6c-372b10fd08b6
6/
  import___4b9c5e01-4ce3-4465-8e81-8fc5f856ce78
  offers___3a673c12-70f8-4f96-b6f0-158d3c32ed11
  prices___38032344-959e-44c7-bfe7-f66f87f0b55a
  rests___18623ce1-1723-461f-8294-66b03197d744
```

Окончание файлов генерируются случайно. Хотел спросить, как возможно с 1с заставить вернуть в `$_REQUEST['filename']` эти файлы в коде 1c_exchange.php на 69 строке или просмотреть.

Есть предложения? Наверное, прошу ответить, что не входит в компетенцию большинства присутствующих здесь, тем не менее надеюсь просто на совет. Очень сложно отследить, что происходит в момент коннекта 1с с файлом 1c_exchange.php и передачи данных сайту. Хотелось глянуть на содержимое массива `$_REQUEST`.

Спасибо за внимание к моему вопросу.